# how to stop automoving opened windows when second monitor connected in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, monitor

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my notebook and when i connect external monitor if it has "left" position configured, all opened windows move to external monitor, if external monitor has "right" position configured, all opened windows stayed on built in monitor. 
How to stop windows moving on external monitor connection regardless of the "left\right"configuration?